# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindDefaults(org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataBuilding

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, nosuchmethoderror

Im trying to solve it an Hibernate problem from yesterday, I already check my libraries and classes and i think im not missing anything, so Im not sure about the real problem on this, the error tha Im getting is:
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindDefaults(org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataBuildingContext)'**

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PThwR.png)

I already uploaded all the correct dependecies/libraries, I hope can be other kind of issue, libraries already are there

[POM imge file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0ezA.png)

Comment: It's common to include your dependencies & versions on questions like this (maybe your pom file or similar?)

Comment: @starball Please + ;) (here the screenshot tells that it's a Maven project, so we can ask for the `pom.xml` file)

Comment: The error could be caused by mismatched versions of your dependencies (please add the content of your `pom.xml` file as text formatted as _Code Sample_ to your question) or by your Hibernate configuration (please show that as well). Does the method exist in your actual dependencies and if yes, with which actual type of parameter it is called?

Comment: already I uploaded the pom image

Comment: Please include the content of your `pom.xml` as text to your question. By the way, when not specifying a Java version in your `pom.xml` Java 5 is used.

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for help me on this, already found the solution, let me share to you the solution in below code format:

```
<dependencies>
    
    <!-- Hibernate framework  5.6.10.Final-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.31</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

this is the correct dependecies structure, now the hibernate configuration is the following:

```
<property name = "hibernate.connection.driver_class"> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  
  <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
  
  <property name = "hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedemo</property>
  
  <property name = "hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  
  <property name = "hibernate.connection.password">mysqlroot</property>
  
  
  <!-- JDBC Connection pool -->
  <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
 
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
  
  <!-- Every session will run in separate thread and thread safe -->
  <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
  
  <!-- Disable second level cache -->
  <property name = "hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>
  
  <!-- Echo all executed sql to stdout -->
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  
  <!-- drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
  <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
  
  <!-- names the annotated entity class -->
  <mapping class="com.to.Player"/>
```

hope can i help you with this, good day!

Comment: as recomendation, if you added a couple of dependencies and then you removed this dependencie, you need to go to the local folder and remove manually all the dependecies that you added, once you did this, try again to add the correct dependencies and your project will be clean and maybe some errors will be removed, this worked to me!